# Gains on test data set higher than that on training data set post balancing

Tags: classification, sampling, cart, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation

I have an imbalanced data set (96-4 split between No and Yes cases). I am trying to build a decision tree model for classification after balancing my data set(tried different thresholds for oversampling and also a combination of under+over sampling), the model seems to have comparatively higher gains on the test data than on the training data across each percentile of the population. How should I interpret this?

Comment: What do you mean by gains? What are you measuring exactly?

Comment: @DavideND i am measuring the percent of churned cases the model captures across each percentile of the population, here is an example of what I mean -> the model captures 19% of churned cases in the 1st 10 percentile of the population on training data but on the test data it captures almost 35% of churned cases in the 1st 10 percentile of the population